# How to Speed up Python code by multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to speed up my Python code by using a multiprocessing.

I read that `ProcessPoolExecutor` will be fir best on my purpose but how can I achieve that.
I have a program like this:

```
    for resource_file in tmp_resource_folder.iterdir():
        with resource_file.open() as f:
            ns_resources = yaml.safe_load(f)
        resources = ns_resources.get('items')

        for resource in resources:
            -----------------
            Slow opperations
            -----------------
```

How it is possible to run each iteration of the first loop into a child process and achieve the speeding up of the code.
Also after the iterations I would like to wait for all child operation to finish before moving on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the **multiprocessing library** ?

Comment: Modify this example that use `Executor.map`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example

Comment: I have never understood the need for the `concurrent.futures` library. `multiprocessing.pool` has basically the same functionality. If you want to wait for the results before moving on, you should use the `map` method of a `multiprocessing.pool`. If you will be iterating over the results after calculation, `imap` will produce an iterator you can use in a `for` loop with the results. If you don't care about order `imap_unordered` will be slightly faster in some cases. If you decide in the future you don't want to wait on the answers, pivot to using `map_async`.

Comment: @Aaron If you use `imap` or `imap_unorderd`, you are not waiting for the answers until you either iterate the results returned by the call or you call `join` on the `Pool` instance and so there is no need to use `map_async` if you do not want to.  But unlike with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` where the main process will not terminate until those tasks submitted to the executor have completed, that is not the case with `multiprocessing.Pool`. **So you better wait at some point for the answers** or you may prematurely terminate before the submitted tasks using `imap` have completed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be the following using `multiprocessing.Pool` with method `imap`:

```py
import multiprocessing

def worker(resource_file):
    with resource_file.open() as f:
        ns_resources = yaml.safe_load(f)
    resources = ns_resources.get('items')

    for resource in resources:
        -----------------
        Slow opperations
        -----------------


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.imap(worker, tmp_resource_folder.iterdir())
    # wait for tasks to finish:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of using `imap`, you can also just use method `map` as follows:

```py
def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(worker, tmp_resource_folder.iterdir())
```

The following is a rather technical description of the difference between `imap` and `map`, which you can ignore. But I suggest you read up on the various `Pool` methods in the `multiprocessing` module.

The potential disadvantage is that the `map` method will effectively treat the call as if you had coded the following:

```py
    pool.map(worker, list(tmp_resource_folder.iterdir()))
```

That is, it will convert the *iterable* argument to a list so that it can take is length. This could result in using a lot of memory if the number of files was extremely large. But it does that so it can compute an efficient *chunksize* value, which is used to set the number of tasks it queues up at a time to each process in the pool in order to reduce the number of memory transfers it has to do queue up the tasks. This can result in improved performance. `imap` by default uses a *chunksize* value of 1, which is not particularly efficient for very large iterables, but you can specify a third argument to `imap`, which is a *chunksize* value to use. But to specify an intelligent value you would really need to know how many files in total you would ultimately be submitting.

The *chunksize* that `map` would compute is essentially the *iterable* size divided by 4 * the pool size:

```py
def compute_chunksize(pool_size, iterable_size):
    chunk_size, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunk_size += 1
    return chunk_size
```

So, for example, if `iterdir()` would ultimately return 30 files and your pool size was 8 (because you had 8 cores), `compute_chunksize` would return 1. If you had from 33 to 64 files, then `compute_chunksize` would return 2.